# What do you get for Tsanna's sacrificial offering in Chapter 7?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

In Chapter 7 - Tsanna offers to sacrifice Evindra to give you the blessings of Lamashtu. If you do it, what benefit do you see for the final battle?

Comment: I'm self-answering this as I had a hard time finding it on the internet. Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the following Blessing of Lamashtu if you have Tsanna sacrifice Evindra.

[image]